# Is there an R function that would produce results similar to SciPy’s gaussian_filter?

Tags: python, r, scipy, gaussian

I’m working to recreate some Python code in R. How can I replicate the results of `gaussian_filter()` from the SciPy package in R ([here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html))? I’ve tried a number of different functions from a number of different packages, and even after ensuring the parameters of these functions match those in the Python function and testing with very basic matrixes they’re producing different results. I can’t find something that is as simple or obvious as what’s offered in Python - am I missing something? If not, what approach should I take to recreating that function in R? Thanks very much!

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve in Python:

```py
gaussian_filter([[1.0,1.0,1.0],[2.0,2.0,2.0],[3.0,3.0,3.0]], sigma=2)

array([[1.88842725, 1.88842725, 1.88842725],
       [2.        , 2.        , 2.        ],
       [2.11157275, 2.11157275, 2.11157275]])
```

This is the [R function](https://rdrr.io/cran/mmand/man/gaussianSmooth.html) that I most expected to work, but the output doesn't match the output from the Python function:

```r
mmand::gaussianSmooth(matrix(rep(1:3, 3), ncol = 3), 2)

         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1.841918 1.841918 1.841918
[2,] 2.000000 2.000000 2.000000
[3,] 2.158082 2.158082 2.158082
```

Comment: Can you please give us some more information, including (1) a link to the documentation of `gaussian_filter()`; (2) a [mcve]; (3) some specific examples (with code) of what you've tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: Showing the output of the Python code on a simple dataset would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Apologies, I should have included some examples. I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I think your example is a little too simple.  You can reproduce the Python output by using a different `sigma` value (i.e. around 2.403 instead of 2), but I wouldn't be confident that the same value would work on other examples.